# sms on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sms

I have a lgg4 and I want to be able to text from my laptop instead of having my phone on me while I am programming. Any known SMS desktop clients that work will doing this, compatible with android and ubuntu? I don't mind having to switch sms apps on my phone, just want to be able to do it. Thanks